# How to instal new look and feel in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

[image: Screen Shot Installed LAF]

Hi , I using **WeblookAndFeel** in my project. Now i need to install the same LookAndFeel in Netbean User-Interface, because its very helpful for me in GUI design, is it possible to install a custom LookAndFeel to netbean..? if yes how.?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607906/how-to-change-the-look-and-feel-in-netbeans-gui-designer-preview

Comment: @rostanek  nope, my question is not about changing preview to 
pre-installed LookAndFeel's like Metal , Nimbus, CDE/Motif, Window, Window Classic, i need to add external look and feel in Netbean GUI

Comment: I think that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7070877/5830089) is answer to your question.

Comment: @rostanek already tried but not working :(  here is my code

netbeans_default_options="--laf com.alee.laf.WebLookAndFeel --cp:p C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.1\WebLaf\weblaf.jar -J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true"