# InternalFrame design changed

Tags: java, swing

I've been developing an app for a long time which has been working fine till lately the design of the swing component's got worse or maybe turned into an older version (You can see the difference in the header of the two images and the JCalender design which is a imported jarfile).

I've tryed creating a new project and copying the source into it still it stay's the same .

So could someone inform me what may be the reason of this happenening ?

**The internal frame with the bad design.**
[image: The internal frame with the bad design]

**The internal frame before this design change happened (How it used to look like).**
[image: The internal frame with good design]

Comment: you are using 2 different look and feels.read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html

Comment: The IDE i use is netbean's just in case you need to know.
Well seem's like your right but in that case . This application that i build is way bigger it has multiple internal frame's ,frame's and 1 MDI frame and the design of each of these frame's changed like the one i showed you .So do you have any clue what could have caused this sudden change ? @FastSnail

Comment: try to change look and feel to metal.2nd one is nimbus 1st one is metal(not sure).find where you set look and feel then change it to metal.in netbeans go to main method.just before the main method there is a section for set look and feel.refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29931454/2227526

Comment: post it as an answer because i solved the problem with your comment so i can choose it as answer. @FastSnail