# Preview design in Netbeans Java is different from runtime design

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, netbeans-8

[image]

Hi this is driving me crazy, I'm working on a project using Netbeans Java IDE and one problem I keep facing is that the preview design is drastically different from the runtime design. I do not know why this keeps happening, I have included both pictures for your references. On top is the picture of the preview design which is what I want the end result to be and below is the runtime design which as you can see is very different from the one on top. I've tried everything and I make sure to compile the code first and then press run, still, the result is different every time. If you know of how to solve this problem do let me know it will help me a lot in my project, thank you so much.

[image]

(Edited) In case you want the code for you to see for yourself:

```
    public class mainpage extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    /**
     * Creates new form mainpage
     */
    public mainpage() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel11 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setUndecorated(true);

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));

        jLabel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel1.setText("Dispatch item");

        jLabel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel2.setText("Stock");

        jLabel3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel3.setText("View records");

        jLabel4.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel4.setText("Home");

        jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 2, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 255));
        jLabel5.setText("Giving.sg");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(40, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 173, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 173, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 129, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 129, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5)))
                .addGap(27, 27, 27))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addComponent(jLabel5)
                .addGap(72, 72, 72)
                .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 46, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(12, 12, 12)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 46, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 46, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(12, 12, 12)
                .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 46, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jPanel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 102, 102));
        jPanel2.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(750, 100));

        jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Noto Sans Javanese", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel6.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel6.setText("Stock management system for covid-19 essentials");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel6)
                .addGap(107, 107, 107))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(20, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel6)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 20)); // NOI18N
        jLabel7.setText("Dispatch item");

        jPanel3.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Dispatch Item", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18))); // NOI18N

        jLabel8.setText("Item type");

        jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Masks", "Face Shields", "Gloves", "Hand Sanitiser", "Wet Tissues" }));
        jComboBox1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jComboBox1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel9.setText("Item name");

        jLabel10.setText("Quantity");

        jLabel11.setText("Dispatch to which row");

        jButton1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
        jButton1.setText("DISPATCH");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
        jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
        jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 141, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(37, 37, 37)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 140, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(44, 44, 44)
                        .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 140, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 41, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(53, 53, 53)
                        .addComponent(jLabel8)
                        .addGap(108, 108, 108)
                        .addComponent(jLabel9)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel10)
                        .addGap(88, 88, 88)))
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 140, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel11))
                .addGap(15, 15, 15))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(32, 32, 32))
        );
        jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel8)
                    .addComponent(jLabel9)
                    .addComponent(jLabel10)
                    .addComponent(jLabel11))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(10, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(45, 45, 45)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel7))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 1038, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 75, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(43, 43, 43)
                .addComponent(jLabel7)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 321, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                          

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(mainpage.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(mainpage.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(mainpage.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(mainpage.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new mainpage().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBox1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel11;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Explicitly set the look and feel.

Comment: I re-edited my post u can see the code now, let me know whats it like on your side as well

Comment: *I'm working on a project using Netbeans Java IDE* - general advice is to NOT use the IDE to generate your code. The code will not be portable to other IDE's. There are so many hardcoded numbers in the code that you don't know what the code is doing. Learning to use layout mangers and generate your own layout. Other issues: 1) class names should start with an upper case character 2) variable names should be meaningful. Using "1, 2, 3..." is not meaningful.

Comment: Your preview is using the system look and feel while your application uses Nimbus. Try `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName())`. Though I have to agree with @camickr. Take the time to learn how to write the code yourself. You'll have more freedom in customization and the code will be easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is, Netbeans is showing preview, based on your system look and feel, by default.

If you want to see different look and feel, Select Design view -> Go to Navigator -> Right click on [JFrame] -> Preview Design -> Nimbus

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scq48.png)

Explanation: Netbeans keeps your drawing in a .xml file. If you go to your src dir -> package of your class, there should be a `mainframe.form` file. As because preview does not execute the original java file, it only prepares the preview from the xml file, it is not possible to identify what 'Look and Feel' you have used in your java code.

If you write any code to change swing components, that change also won't reflect in the design preview.

For more details:
[How to change the look and feel in NetBeans GUI Designer Preview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607906/how-to-change-the-look-and-feel-in-netbeans-gui-designer-preview)

If you use Netbeans, my suggestion is, expand the `Generated Code` in your java file, and observe, what code is generated against your drawing. This is how you can learn swing quickly.